# in React.js data-reactid is breaking html text input?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hi so my React component renders in the html and works with one catch.

The Catch is "data-reactid=".0.0"" this breaks the input and prevents you from being able to type in it. As soon as i remove/change this the input works again.

My React Component:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('../../../../node_modules/react/react.js');
// react component DateBox will return a date time that updates every 50 miliseconds and appends it to a div with an id of 'date_box'
var GoogleSearchBox = React.createClass({
    GetValueFromGoogleSearchInput: function(event){
        var GoogleSearch = document.getElementById("google_search_input");
        var UserSearchQuery = GoogleSearch.value.toString().replace(/ /g,"+");
        var GET = "http://google.com/#q=" + UserSearchQuery;
        window.open(GET, '_blank');
    },
    //rendering the html elements with the state.clock
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="google_search">
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Type here to search google" name="google_search_input" id="google_search_input">
                </input>
                <div>
                    <button id="google_search_button" onClick={this.GetValueFromGoogleSearchInput}></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}); 
//rendering with react to put onto the html
module.exports = GoogleSearchBox;
```

How it renders in html:

```
<div id="google_search_box">
    <div class="google_search" data-reactid=".0">
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Type here to search google" name="google_search_input" id="google_search_input" data-reactid=".0.0">
        <div data-reactid=".0.1">
            <button id="google_search_button" data-reactid=".0.1.0"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your text field is not responding to user input because you created a [Controlled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) by manually setting the `value` prop.

> An `<input>` with `value` set is a controlled component. In a controlled
>   `<input>`, the value of the rendered element will always reflect the
>   `value` prop.

If you would like to set a default value but allow the text field to respond to user input, consider setting the `defaultValue` prop instead.

```
<input type="text" defaultValue="" placeholder="Type here to search google" name="google_search_input" id="google_search_input">
```